# How i find related cell value in DBF file using C# code

Tags: c#

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k46BA.png)

Please Help me and explain where am I wrong in below C# Code. My requirement take the output as related columns(E7) cell value.but when I use below code there output is a count of that cell, please advice me, how can I correct this?

```
private void btn_Attach_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    string LogFolder = @"C:\Log\";

    try
    {
         string CellToRead = "A2";
         string CellName = "";
         Int32 CellNumber;
         string fileFullPath = @"C:\Users\Pavan\Desktop\IT"; 
         string CellValue = "";

         var alphanumericstring = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
         var match = alphanumericstring.Match(CellToRead);

         CellName = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;
         int.TryParse(match.Groups["Numeric"].Value, out CellNumber);

         string ConStr;
         ConStr = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV; User ID=;Password=;"); 

         OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
         cnn.Open();

         System.Data.DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

         OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select * from CSHMIMP0.dbf ["+CellName +(CellNumber - 1).ToString()+ ":" + CellToRead + "]", cnn);
         OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);

         System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
         adp.Fill(dt);

         cnn.Close();

         foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
         {
             object[] array = row.ItemArray;
             CellValue = array[0].ToString();
         }

         Console.WriteLine("CelltoRead :" + CellToRead + "   Cell Value:" + CellValue);
         Console.ReadLine();
     }
     catch (Exception exception)
     {
         using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(LogFolder + "\\" + "ErrorLog_" + datetime + ".log"))
         {
             sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
         }
     }
}
```

E7 cell Value is "MCROYALE"

Comment: Dear Sir, previous, I tried this code to read the related value from the Excel .it's work properly. now I use this code for the read related value of the DBF files. Thanks, sir

Comment: My Qusion is how to ready single value from DBF file

Comment: foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
         {
             object[] array = row.ItemArray;
             CellValue = array[0].ToString();
         }

         Console.WriteLine("CelltoRead :" + CellToRead + "   Cell Value:" + CellValue);
         Console.ReadLine();
     }
     catch (Exception exception)

Comment: when I execute the above code, output will come as court of the column but I need read only MIMDSC column Row #7 record value ( (E7)-uploaded the image)